# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE importing only one row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Using MySQL Database, I want to import a csv file with 13 columns and 120 rows. I am trying to upload them into a table.

Here is my command:

```
mysql> load data local infile 'restaurants.csv' 
       into table restaurants_restaurant fields        
       terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n';
```

Here is what was reported:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 4 warnings (0.05 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 4
```

Only 1 row was added, and only partially?  What am I doing wrong?

My Table Structure:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
location= models.CharField(max_length=200)
address= models.CharField(max_length=500)
phone_number= models.IntegerField()
email= models.CharField(max_length=200)
description= models.CharField(max_length=2000)
hours= models.CharField(max_length=200)
photos= models.CharField(max_length=200)
price= models.CharField(max_length=200)
rating= models.IntegerField()
review= models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

First 4 lines of my csv:

```
American Burger,American,Dhaka,,,,,,,,2 to 4,4
ARIRANG,Korean,Dhaka,,"House 3, Road 51, Gulshan 2, Dhaka, Bangladesh.",(88-02) 989-6453,,,,,,
Aroma,,Dhaka,,,,,,,,15 to 20,3.5
Bacaru,,Dhaka,,,,,,,,,4
```

Comment: I would guess for a subtle mismatch of column types ... would you mind editing your post with the table definition and the first few rows of your csv-file?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure SQL solution here?

Comment: What Morten says. We need to see the data

Comment: Hope the additional info helps

Comment: when I've had this before, it been because the line termination character was wrong. eg if the import file was created by a Mac, it might be `\r` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @cms_mgr im looking for anything that works - as long as I can get this data into my db. thanks

Comment: @SDC I tried \r and it works for the first 13 rows perfectly. however only 13 rows are added 
    mysql> load data local infile 'restaurants.csv' into table    
    restaurants_restaurant fields terminated by ';' enclosed by '"' 
    lines terminated by '\r' (name);

    Query OK, 13 rows affected, 15 warnings (0.11 sec)
    Records: 13  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 15

Comment: Could we see row 14? It seems one of your problems is in there. I'm going to guess one of your fields includes a comma.

Comment: 12    Best Fried Chicken,Fast Food,Dhaka,,,,,,,,5 to 7,4
13    "Bhitika Restaurant, Sheraton",Continental,Dhaka,,,,,,,,,3.5
14    Boomers,,Dhaka,,,,,,,,,3
15    BUKHARA,Indian,Dhaka,,"Iqbal Center (18th Floor), 42, Kemal    
    Ataturk Avenue, Banani, Dhaka, Bangladesh.",(88-02) 881-2411,,,,,,

Comment: There's a field on both row 13 and on row 15 which had a comma but is surrounded by '"'

Comment: Got it to work by adding in the column names at the end:
    mysql> load data local infile 'restaurants.csv' into table    
    restaurants_restaurant fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'       
    lines terminated by '\r'  
    (name,address,email,category,city,rating,price,location);

Answer (score 1):

In your CSV file line separator is (0D 0A). So, you need to use '\r\n' as line separator -

```
...
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Comment: mysql> load data local infile 'restaurants.csv' into table    
    restaurants_restaurant fields terminated by ';' enclosed by '"' 
    lines terminated by '\r\n' (name);
    Query OK, 1 row affected, 13 warnings (0.12 sec)
    Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 13

Answer (score 0):

If you have any unique constraints on your table that your data file rows are violating, then `LOAD DATA INFILE` will skip them, as illustrated in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913896/445131

Either remove all the unique constraints on your table and try again, or remove the duplicates in each column of each row in the text file and try again.